# compiling python to windows exe

Tags: python

I have some supportscript written in python that I thought would be nice to be able to run on client computers. So I was thinking about wrapping them in a GUI and compiling them to an .exe file, which of course seem troublesome.

I gave Pyinstaller a shot but with no luck so I moved forward to nuitka. This works with simple "hello world" scripts, but I need GUI and must be doing something wrong.

My environment is Windows7 x64 with 32-bit Python 2.7 (and 3.4) and  Vs2010, 2013 installed.
I've tried different versions of the following command

```
nuitka --exe --recurse-all --standalone --windows-disable-console --python-version=2.7 helloTk.py
```

With TK it works on my developer machine, but if I move the Hello.dist folder to another machine nothing happens when I execute it, no errors, nothing.
With QT5 I get a warning from nutika which states something about it's unable to resolve QT imports.

So what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Regards

Comment: I had the same task a year ago and used cx_freeze which worked for me (win7, pyside) - have a look: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html

Comment: Be sure to have the needed .dll files. By the way, I usually use PyInstaller (python 2.7, PyQt4, Windows 7 x64) and it works perfectly. I highly suggest that.

Comment: Yes, nuitka puts a lot of DLL files in the "dist" folder but I guess something is missing anyway since nothing happens at all on my target computer when I run the .exe. Thanks for the hint about cx-freeze, maybe it's time to move on again. I tried pyinstaller but it couldn't read it's spec files so I never got an .exe filefrom it